# Category description to category list page

Tags: php, opencart

How to get category descrption to category list page which lists subcategories.
For example I have Shoes-page which lists all subcategorys:

```
Nike, Adidas, Puma
```

Now I want to have description text on this Shoes-page like:

```
Nike - This is description text.
Adidas - This is description text2.
Puma - This is description text3.
```

At this moment description text is shown **inside** of Nike page, but how to get it to Shoes-page?

I see in category.tpl file thise:

```
<?php if ($description) { ?>
<?php echo $description; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Which handels description, but do I need to place it somewhere else or what need to be done?

Comment: This is very chaotic description @user1720534, try to describe it in more readable way. Thank You.

Comment: I do not get the problem. Where should the category description be displayed?

Comment: @user1720534 your question was much explanatory initially than its now

Comment: @shadyyx i guess he want the decryption of the subcategories on parent category page where subcategories are listed as simple list elements without description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to pass subcategories' description from controller to tpl file,

in `catalog\controller\product\category.php`

find

```
'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
```

just after this line add the following line

```
'description' => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
```

Now in your tpl file that is `catalog\view\theme\your_theme\template\product\category.tpl`

you have to add `<?php echo $category['description'];?>` inside the following loop

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

P.S. Edit your question to inital one, it was more explanatory than it is now